# How to trigger a refresh/reload when a page crosses a certain resolution back and forth only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have a page [www.redpeppermedia.in/tc24_beta/](http://www.redpeppermedia.in/tc24_beta/) it works fine over `980px` resolution but as you bring it down to `768px`, the CSS and media queries change the layout of it, but once you are in the `768px` and you refresh the page, everything becomes as I want, the layouts fix itself. And now if you try to resize it to more than `768px` you need to refresh again so as the layout fixes..

I mean is there a better way to do it... or can anyone help me with this refreshing and reloading thing..

Thank You so much though :)

Answer (score 0):

$( window ).width()take a tour of `window.resize` in jquery :

```
var old_size = $( window ).width();

$( window ).resize(function() {
  if(old_size > 768 && $( window ).width() < 768){
    window.location.reload();
  }
  old_size = $( window ).width();
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it reloads the page everytime you try to resize within the 768px resolution...
And I don't want that to happen

Comment: Store old value in variable and check it inside a resize function. Check my edited answer.

Comment: it doesn't refresh itself when you are out of the 768px resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this amazing script that did my work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var limit = 768;            

    function refresh() {
        ww = $(window).width();
        var w =  ww<limit ? (location.reload(true)) :  ( ww>limit ? (location.reload(true)) : ww=limit );
    }

    var tOut;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var resW = $(window).width();
        clearTimeout(tOut);                 
        if ((ww>limit && resW<limit) || (ww<limit && resW>limit) ) {        
            tOut = setTimeout(refresh, 100);
        }
    });
});
```